# HTML: Giving image map area color

Tags: html, colors, imagemap

I have a file where a map image ("worldmap.jpg") is displayed, on which there is a clickable area ("Site_1"):

```
<img src="worldmap.jpg" width="1425" height="1296" alt="World" usemap="#worldmap">      

<map name="worldmap">           
    <area shape="circle" coords="350,320,50" alt="Site_1" href="site1.htm">
</map>
```

Is there a way to make the clickable area visible (that is, make the circle green)?

Comment: "area" cannot be styled with CSS... so either you add that green circle directly to the image by editing it or you add another div with some styling and place it in the same place as the area.

Comment: Some people also suggest using this, which seems better: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/